# Accident delete disk BLOB with Windows Azure (MSA) Virtual Machine (VM)

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, disaster-recovery

I was in list Virtual Machines, switch to Cloud Services, click to delete one, BUT Azure portal was somelike freeze at first tab and remove me VM!!!

I tried to do something with support but exist there only call support.

What can I do? 
How can I know undelete data BLOB?
Where to go?

Answer (score 0):

There is no `undelete` feature in Storage service.

The best you can do is to contact support and hope they can do anything about this.

Anyway it is really strange behavior you observed. And all delete operations do ask whether you are sure you want to complete the operation. Either you didn't carefully read what is the confirmation about, or really there has been issue with the portal. Fact is that I've been using the portal ever since its preview and never occurred such behavior. But you never know what could happen...

Comment: Exactly I tried this function serveral times that I was sure for production enviroment. But now I use better command line API.

Comment: The best you can do is to contact support and hope they can do anything about this.

Answer (score 0):

Without subscription nobody from Microsoft help with deleted VM.

There is no recommend in current date from MS.